# how to handle complex bash parameters?

Tags: bash, parameters

How can I consume parameters as complex as the ["Terminology example" from the bash-hackers wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial#terminology), which doesn't cover it after presenting.

```
mybackup -x -f /etc/mybackup.conf -r ./foo.txt ./bar.txt

These are all positional parameters, but they can be divided into several logical groups:

    -x is an option (aka flag or switch). It consists of a dash (-) followed by one character.
    -f is also an option, but this option has an associated option argument (an argument to the option -f): /etc/mybackup.conf. The option argument is usually the argument following the option itself, but that isn't mandatory. Joining the option and option argument into a single argument -f/etc/mybackup.conf is valid.
    -r depends on the configuration. In this example, -r doesn't take arguments so it's a standalone option like -x.
    ./foo.txt and ./bar.txt are remaining arguments without any associated options. These are often used as mass-arguments. For example, the filenames specified for cp(1), or arguments that don't need an option to be recognized because of the intended behavior of the program. POSIX® calls them operands.

To give you an idea about why getopts is useful, The above command line is equivalent to:

mybackup -xrf /etc/mybackup.conf ./foo.txt ./bar.txt
```

Comment: well the details are all covered by their infomation on `getopts`. you are just looking at a page of definitions. you may want to start with a page like this: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/getopts.htm

Comment: There are many ways to do this; see [BashFAQ #35: "How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) and the stackoverflow question ["How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/29754866#29754866)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the bash built-in command [getopts](https://ss64.com/bash/getopts.html). it is an advanced command line parser, which makes it easier to consume options and arguments and operands within bash scripts.

There are many tutorials out there on `getopts`. I recommend searching online for "bash getopts" so you don't get C/C++ results (C/C++ programmers often us a tool for the same purpose with the same name, and almost identical usage, but the code syntax is C-ish).

This tutorial for instance covers all the different argument types your definitions mention: https://www.stackchief.com/tutorials/Bash%20Tutorial%3A%20getopts

Comment: the wiki linked in the question have a more complex documentation than the one linked here. And even that one doesn't cover the complex cases it uses when defining the terminology. I would like to cover both flags, --longflags and positional params.

Comment: your question doesn't reflect any of that, you know. give us your own examples of code and show us what you have tried with getopts to parse it.